# Why does this let me get a non-const pointer to a field of a const object?

Tags: c++, constants

I am compiling this snippet with clang++ ("Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)"), although GCC also does it just fine:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    typedef unsigned char MemoryPage[0x1000];

    MemoryPage* pages;

    Foo() { pages = new MemoryPage[16]; }
    ~Foo() { delete[] pages; }

    unsigned char* PointerToOffset(unsigned offset) const
    {
        return pages[offset >> 12] + (offset & 0xfff);
    }
};
```

And it compiles just fine. I'm surprised because `PointerToOffset` has the `const` qualifier, but the return value is a non-`const` `unsigned char` pointer.

I could also ensure that it returns values inside the memory range of `pages`, which means I get an actual non-`const` pointer to the actual `const` object data, and not a dangling reference to an eventual copy of the target array.

The result, it seems, is a const-incorrect method that compiles nonetheless. What makes it legal?

Comment: It's as const-incorrect as `int *const` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simplest words the variable,

```
MemoryPage* pages;
```

will become as:

```
MemoryPage* const pages;  // and not `const MemoryPage*`
//          ^^^^^
```

inside your `const` function: `PointerToOffset()`.

The meaning of `const` is that a class variable *cannot be modified*. To make `pages` an unmutable entity, the `const` has to apply on `pages` itself and not the contents pointed by it.
That's why there is no error in the compiler.

For the sake of understanding, simpy try declaring `pages` as `const MemoryPage*` and then you will notice that compiler will emit error even in non-const functions.

Comment: Why does it become `MemoryPage* const` instead of `const MemoryPage*`? It doesn't seem to me that it's what it should be doing. If it was a `char` pointer, it would become a `const char*` after all.

Comment: @zneak, added the explanation to your question. If you want to modify `pages` then you write like: `pages = x;` and not `*pages = x;`. In `const` functions, the class member variables should not be modified. So `pages` become `T* const` instead of `const T*`.